# Creating a TCP Socket in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sockets, tcp

In PHP it is easy to create, connect an interact with a TCP socket (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP, the Client part).

How can I accomplish this in AngularJS?
Tried the module on following site: https://github.com/BHSPitMonkey/angular-net-sockets, but failed. An example on this site would have been helpful to me.

**EDIT**

How can I use that in my controller? I'm getting the error: 'factory must return a value'.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'netsockets',  function ($scope, netsockets) {
$scope.username = "test";

$scope.send_socket = function(){
    socket.connect('1.1.1.1','1111');
    socket.sendData('hello world');
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
};
```

}]);

This is my factory:

```
factory('netsockets', function(NetSocket) {
    return {
    init: function(){
        var socket = new NetSocket({
          onConnect: function(){
              alert('I\'m connected!');
          },
          onDisconnect: function(){
              alert('I\'m disconnected!');
          }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  factory('MyService', function(NetSocket) {
    var socket = new NetSocket({
      onConnect: function() {
        alert('I\'m connected!');
      },
      onDisconnect: function() {
        alert('I\'m disconnected!');
      }
    });
    socket.connect('1.1.1.1','1111');
    socket.sendData('hello world');
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
});
```

**EDIT**

your factory does not return anything. Try with this:

```
factory('netsockets', function(NetSocket) {
    return new NetSocket({
          onConnect: function(){
              alert('I\'m connected!');
          },
          onDisconnect: function(){
              alert('I\'m disconnected!');
          }
        });

});
```

Comment: please see my comment